# Issue getting AccordionContainer with dijit.byId with IE

Tags: dojo

I have 3 content panes in an accordion container:

```
<div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="center" splitter="false" id="innerContentPaneCenter">
    <div dojoType="dijit.layout.AccordionContainer" id="accordion_container">
        <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Search" selected="true" id="search_accordion_pane">
            ... snip ...
        </div>
        <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Edit Record" id="visit_accordion_pane">
            ... snip ...
        </div>
        <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Legend" id="legend_accordion_pane">
            ... snip ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, I am trying to get the accordion widget with:

```
accordion_container = dijit.byId("accordion_container");
```

So that I can programmatically open this pane:

```
accordion_container.selectChild("visit_accordion_pane");
```

The `dijit.byId` line fails in IE with the message:

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method
```

This code works nicely in Chrome and FF.

I am getting this result in Dojo Version 1.6.1.

What am I doing wrong? What is the issue?

Thanks

Comment: What version of dojo are you using?

Comment: 1. Is it the dijit.byId which fails in IE, or the selectChild call ?
2. IF it is the dijit.byId, are you sure the parser has been called ?
3. If the parser has been called, are you sure that you have required the accordeon widget before your dojo.ready ?

Answer (score 1):

You will not get a node with dijit.byId...

dijit.byId returns a... dijit ! and it is used like dijit.byId(idOfMyWidget) :)
if your widget is a _Widget, then you *could* do a dijit.byId().containerNode

if you want to get a node directly, use dojo.byId() instead.

Answer (score 1):

As PEM says, you're getting a widget, not a node, which is what you want.  You say this is failing on the first line (calling `dijit.byId`) not the second, so it sounds like the problem has nothing to do with the accordion, but the reference to `dijit.byId` itself.  Where is this line of code?  Is it wrapped in a `dojo.ready`/`dojo.addOnLoad` callback?

Comment: I fixed that... changed 'node' to 'widget' in my question. `dijit.byId` is in a function that is eventually wrapped in dojo.ready. That is, the dojo.onready calls the init function which sets up the page so that the user is able to make changes.

Comment: so what's the exception, exactly?  is `dijit` undefined?  Might need to see the complete page.  The problem probably exists outside the snippet posted.